# The class of languages that can be certified in a small amount of space

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes, space-complexity

NP can be characterized in two different ways, one of them is that it's the class of languages that can be certified by a witness in a polynomial time.

I wonder, if we consider the same notion but with space considerations to get a class $X$, Is such a class known to be of any importance? Why?

To be more precise, $L\in X$ iff there exists a TM $M$ s.t.

$\forall x\in \{0,1\}^* (x\in L \iff  \exists u \in \{0,1\}^{p(n)}$ s.t. $M(x,u)=1$ s.t. $M$ uses space bounded by a polynomial $P$.

Clearly, NP$\subset$ X. Is there any interesting thing that we can know about $X$?

Answer (score 3):

(Note that X is not known to differ from NP.) ​ Yes - X is equal to [PSPACE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSPACE). ​ In fact, one gets that from just brute force, rather than needing [Savitch's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitch%27s_theorem).

You might also be interested in [NL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NL_(complexity)), which is only known to satisfy

L ​ $\subseteq$ ​ NL ​ $\subseteq$ ​ [coN](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:C#conp)L[O](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:L#loglog)G[LOGTIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLOGTIME)-[unifor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_complexity#Uniformity)m [SAC<sup>1</sup>](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:S#sac1) ​ ​ .

(Note that, to get a certificate characterization of NL, we probably must

"[restrict the verifier to have *one-way access* to the certificate](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~salil/cs221/spring10/PS2.pdf)".)